# Issue with jQuery.ajax() for pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination, magento-1.6

I'm using magento as my CMS, trying to implement ajax for pagination,

I have 2 pages at the moment, the structure is such,

```
<div class="pager">
        <div class="pages">
          <strong>Page:</strong>
          <ol>
             <li class="current">1</li>
             <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/Bakestore/index.php/tools.html?p=2" class="pageLinks">2</a></li>
             <li class="pager_next_img">
                <a class="next i-next pageLinks" href="http://localhost/Bakestore/index.php/tools.html?p=2" title="Next">
                <img src="http://localhost/Bakestore/skin/frontend/default/Bakestore_Theme/images/pager_arrow_right.gif" alt="Next" class="v-middle">
                </a>
            </li>
          </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

my jQuery ajax code is as below,

```
$j(".pages li a").each(function(){
    $j(this).removeClass('pageLinks').addClass('pageLinks');                                
});

$j(".pageLinks").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchorSel =  $j(this).attr('href');
    $j.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        datatype: "HTML",
        cache: true,
        url: anchorSel,

        success: function(data){
            var testdata = $j(data).find(".category-products");
            $j(".col-main .category-products").replaceWith(testdata);
            },

        complete: function(data){
                        $j(".pages li a").each(function(){
                            $j(this).removeClass('pageLinks').addClass('pageLinks');                            });
                            alert($j(".col-main .category-products .toolbar > .pager").html());
                         }
});
```

It works fine when I click `Page 2`, but, from page 2 when I hit `Page 1`, the page reloads. Now when I hit `Page 2` again, it works fine.

I debugged my jQuery, sadly, the event `$j(".pageLinks").click` is not getting fired at all (when I click on `Page 1`).

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your return html contains the pagination links?
if thats the case, you need to change `.click(function(){` to `.live('click', function(){`

click binds only existing elements to that event handler. live does the same except also for elements that have yet to come into existence.

live is indeed deprecated. if you are using 1.7, which i dont think you are. you should change it to

```
$(document).on('click', ".pageLinks", function(){

});
```

Comment: Ok, this is working, can you please explain as to why this works? Thanks, will accept answer then :)

Comment: Note that [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+, but if it works for your version, alright.

Comment: you could use .on() that was introduced in jQuery 1.7 as a substitute of .live().

Comment: The [API page](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has examples of which versions support and should use `.live`, `.delegate` and `.on`. :P Thanks for edit Funky.

Comment: The reason .click() doesn't works is because the event is unbinded when you removeClass when the AJAX call is complete.  
on() and previously bind() binds the event to the supplied selector, it doesn't matter if you removeClass or remove the element and then add it again.  

At least this is the way I understand it (I asked this same question some months ago)

Comment: If I may ask... why you do this?  

`$j(".pages li a").each(function(){
    $j(this).removeClass('pageLinks').addClass('pageLinks');                                
});`

Comment: @davidaam it's not needed, I wasn't thinking right at the time, removed it.

Comment: @Tarun Don't worry, that happens to me all the time when I haven't slept well :)

Comment: Help me on the pagination issue.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316910/magento-2-custom-added-ajax-pagination-not-working